# Block 169.254.169.254 from dockerfile on Google CloudRun

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I'm exploring any potential solution to prevent my software, which runs on Google Cloud Run and executes untrusted code, from accessing the metadata server.

I considered using iptables for this purpose, but encountered limitations due to the lack of access to the Docker host environment on Cloud Run. Given that iptables operates at the kernel level, which requires access to the host's network stack; a level of control not available in the fully managed Cloud Run environment. I realized this approach is not possible.

I also tried with entrypoint, to apply iptables on start but this is not possible either on Cloud Run.

Am I overlooking anything? Is my understanding accurate? What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iptables, but you must use the 2nd generation Cloud Run execution environment, as it provides better Linux compatibility by specifying `--execution-environment gen2`.

Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y iptables && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Entrypoint.sh (just 80 & 443 so DNS isn't blocked on 53)

```bash
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.169.254 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 169.254.169.254 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Deployment command

```bash
gcloud run deploy ip-filter --image europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/project-id/dev-images/ip-filter --platform managed --region europe-west2 --allow-unauthenticated --execution-environment gen2
```

Console Error when requesting `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/`

`'Connection to metadata.google.internal timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))`

Sample Repo: https://github.com/pmgledhill102/cloudrun-firewall-metadata

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for the quality of your response but with this iptables rule all my outgoing traffic seems blocked. Does it interfere with some google cloud rules ?

Comment: You're correct - as my original solution blocked all access to `169.254.169.254` I think it was blocking DNS look-ups on port 53. I've tried with explicit blocks on ports 80 and 443, and this seems to block requests to the metadata service, but still allow requests to other websites. I've updated my answer, and my repo.